# GENEXUS: Colección API REST por procedure

Tags: mysql, api, rest, genexus, postman

Estoy practicando con GX17 U9, y me pidieron que cree una API REST por procedure a la cual se le deberá ingresar varios parámetros (en este caso varios DNI) para que devuelva un solo JSON con los datos almacenados bajo esos DNI (nombre, tel, fecha de nacimiento, etc). No sabría cómo encararlo ya que la documentación de GX se me hace muy confusa.
Lo que fui haciendo es hacer un sdt con la transacción y un procedure con las propiedades http, pero en postman no carga nada. Les agradecería mucho la ayuda

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) gracias por ayudar a esta comunidad. pero debes ser mas especifico, muéstranos que has intentado, dale un vistazo al siguiente contenido [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

No logré entender si ya tenés el procedure programado (carga el SDT a partir de los datos filtrando por el DNI recibido por parámentro), partiendo de la base que si lo tenés, podes tomar dos caminos:

1. El procedure exponerlo como rest.
   Basicamente deberia tener como paramétro de IN el DNI y de OUT una variable basada en el SDT con los datos.
   Ese procedure tiene que exponerse como WService y REST.
   https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?21467,Procedures+as+Rest+web+services+in+GeneXus
2. Usar un API object (que es lo más prolijo). Este objecto API es el que expone la interfaz e internamente llama al procedure que carga el SDT.
   https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?50879,API+Object+Syntax#Samples

Comment: Buen día! Muchísimas por responder! En realidad hago, no me sale y lo borro al procedure, así que se podría decir que tengo el procedure en blanco